# Is there a way to trigger a React update through Django?

Tags: django, reactjs, api, redux, django-rest-framework

I am working on an application with a Django backend and React frontend.

The Django backend currently receives text messages as they are received (no polling). I would like to know how to update my React application with the post data from the text message request (that was received in Django) **as the texts are received** (no polling), all while using the Django Rest Framework?

I've looked online but I haven't found much information specific to this problem. From what I've read it seems Redux might be the answer, but I'm very new to React and have only briefly looked into Redux so I'm not sure. Also from what I've read online, people have said only use Redux if you **have to** due to the steep learning curve so I'm wondering if anyone with more experience can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Websockets sound like they'd suit your need. There's a brief article here on real time messaging with Django and React: https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/a-simple-real-time-chat-with-django-channels-and-react-b73edc3a79f2

Answer (score 2):

Hey I'm not a react guy I use vue but I do work with DRF and Django. You should not need redux for this unless you're using your API to update the state across your entire project. You can implement this type of update cycle with something as simple plain JS onload property that fires the get or post request to update the page. If you need it to update more instantaneously and don't want to implement redux you can update the "local state" using state hooks(i believe is what react calls them) this will allow for information to be updated when the call is run without reloading the entire page.

I use Axios for api calls this will return the JSON data you need to update your page. I hope this didn't come across as patronizing i have no idea what your skill level is and i try to answer so anyone can get it.

Comment: Not patronizing at all! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not making things complicated.

There are two ways which you can do this:

*Easy way but not great*
Give an HTTP Request to your server via React then wait for the response then update your view on the basis of the response. You can run this API Request at different intervals.

*Real way*
Create a socket connection that will help your server to send messages directly to the react application when subscribed to it. For creating a socket with django `django-channels` can be used. This will require you to reconfigure your server for new ASGI server.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be an issue, with or without the usage of redux.

Your react component will re-render as long as the components state or props have changed.

Therefore, what you should do, is to listen to the receiving of your text messages on the frontend (React), and update your state or props accordingly.